# returning a double in the floating stack using __asm in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, return-value, inline-assembly, calling-convention

I am using MS Visual Studio (2005, but that should not be important).
I have a function whose body is implemented (necessarily) in inline assembly:

```
double f(double x)
{
    __asm{ ...body code... }
}
```

The assembly code finishes with the result to be returned contained in ST0.
The calling convention being used is __cdecl, so the convention is that a return double value is returned in ST0.  Thus, after the __asm{...body code...} code is completed, the function is ready to have its returning stack-cleanup code run and ret.  However, the code above will not compile, of course, because there is no "return dblVal;" statement.  It could be corrected by changing the code to:

```
double f(double x)
{
    double dRet;
    __asm{ ...body code... }
    __asm{ fst dRet }
    return dRet;
}
```

but this has two disadvantages:
(1) the store to dRet is immediately followed by fld dRet, which is a complete waste and unnecessary (and this is being used innumerable times in a monte-carlo routine, so every cycle counts)
(2) more importantly, the value in ST0 has been carefully computed in the body to 64-bit-mantissa accuracy, which I need to preserve, and the fst followed by fld completely kills this.

How can I tell the VisualStudio compiler that the double to be returned is already in ST0?
I could write the exit code explicitly:

```
double f(double x)
{
    __asm{ ...body code... }
    __asm{ __asm leave
           __asm ret
         }
    return 0.0; //dummy code that is never executed, to make the compiler happy
}
```

but then one has to know the entry code that that the compiler generates (and in fact, the exit code above is wrong).  So we could take this further, and write both the entry code and the exit code:

```
__declspec ( naked ) double f(double x)
{
    __asm{ ...entry code...}
    __asm{ ...body code... }
    __asm{ ...exit code... }
    return 0.0; //dummy code that is never executed, to make the compiler happy
}
```

but that is all VERY ugly.  So, how do I get the compiler to look after the entry code and exit code, and tell it that the return value is already in ST0?

Comment: Why are you declaring a function and then putting the internals all in inline assembly?  Why not skip the C declaration altogether and only have the function exist in actual assembly as opposed to inline assembly in a C file?

Comment: maintainability: it's part of a very large application, and I just don't have the time to integrate actually assembly.

Comment: But you are correct, it would be better to just use proper assembly.  I just don't have the time to do all the work (learning mostly), and it would add even more confusion for the other developers, who already run in fear of just assembly instructions, let alone creating a module for the assembler (and setting up assembly into the project, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the answer to my question is that I was wrong about one thing in the statements of the question above:

```
double f(double x)
{
    __asm{ ...body code... }
}
```

without any return statement, with the __asm statements in the body, compiles just fine, without any errors or warnings.  The compiler assumes (correctly) that I have arranged for the return values to be passed/returned appropriately.  The compiler correctly generates the entry and exit codes and is happy leaving the rest to me.  Go figure - why did I think I had tested that and found compile errors?  Sigh. Sorry for bothering everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you only option is naked functions, however they don't require a C return statement, nor are you required to do stack frames. however, unless you have a really good reason to use asm, your way better of doing it in C for many reasons , mainly portability and the other being target specific optimization, like SIMD.

Comment: I do have a really good reason to use assembly: I need a series of calculations done with the 80-bit precision, and they need to be done very fast.  SIMD is absolutely NOT what we need - we need higher precision, not less precision.